# show full post in the_excerpt()

Tags: php, wordpress, post

This will set word limit on the_excrept() to 9999:

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 9999;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

It works to show a pretty big excerpt but it's a bad solution to my problem when all I wan't to do is to show all words from the_post() in the_excerpt(). Anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Than why don't u use. the_content(); function it will show full content of post.

check reference here

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: The reason why I must use the_excerpt() is that I can't use the_content() in a specific place of the site. But if there is no solution then 9999 words will have to do.

Comment: Why couldn't you use it?  Anywhere that you can use `the_excerpt()` you can use `the_content()`.

Comment: It has to do with wpautop and alot of old blog posts imported from a non wordpress blog.

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt is a short extract from a post. If you want to show the entire post content then you're using the wrong function.

Replace `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()`.

If there's some reason you want to show all the post content inside `the_excerpt()` you could use:

```
function wpse_replace_excerpt_with_content( $excerpt ) {
    return get_the_content();
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpse_replace_excerpt_with_content' );
```

I can't imagine why you'd want to do this but it is possible.

Comment: Will this be full length excerpts without any html tags?

Comment: No. I read your comment on the other answer. There are filters that can be removed and functions to strip HTML. Those should be used.